# python natural logarithms print error

Tags: python

i have an exercise to do in Python which asks the user to give 2 numbers x and y. OK i got that. then it needs to print the exponential value of e to the power of x, where e is the base of the natural logarithm.
up to now i have:

```
x=int(input('Please state the value of X: '))
y=int(input('Please state the value of Y: '))

print(math.log(x[,base]))
```

apparently it returns an error for invalid syntax of the comma separator prior to the word base.
is the coding correct or am i missing something?

Comment: Well what is the `[,base]` expect to do?

Comment: Furthermore it is not clear to me why you query for `y` since you do not do anything with that.

Comment: `exponential value of e to the power of x` == e^x? => `math.e**x`

Comment: When the documentation says `math.log(x[,base])`, it means that the second argument, `base`, is optional.  It doesn't mean that you need to literally type the square brackets and the word `base`.

Comment: Also, if you're trying to compute an exponential, then why are you taking the logarithm?  They are inverse operations.  You can get the value of `e` from `math.e`, then use `math.e**x` to raise it to the power of `x`.  If you want to raise x to the y, you can do `x**y`.

Comment: What is the y variable for?

Answer (score 0):

You should **ommit the `[,base]` part**:

```
print(math.log(x))
```

This is *syntax* in the *documentation* to specify that parameter(s) are optional. It thus means that you **do not have to specify a base**. Like we can see in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.log):

> **`math.log(x[, base])`**
>
> With **one argument**, return the natural logarithm of x (to base e).
>
> With **two arguments**, return the logarithm of x to the given base,
>   calculated as `log(x)/log(base)`.

That being said, if you want to calculate the result of "*e to the power of x*", then you need to **use [`math.exp`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.exp)** instead:

```
print(math.exp(x))
```